# Why does my modem takes many attempts to connect to internet

Tags: networking, router, internet, modem, isp

I have this old DSL 502T Dlink modem router(wired). I have been using this for many years without any issues.

Recently though, there is issue connecting to the Internet (WAN side). It takes many attempts (restarts of modem) to connect to the internet for the first time, that is when my PC and Modem are started. It takes minimum 3-4 restarts of modem to get an internet connection working. Otherwise, the WAN connection remains disconnected, although the internal LAN works.

I have tried starting Modem first before PC, and also PC first before modem but this does not resolve the issues. Also, once the WAN(Internet) connection is obtained, it remains stable throughout the day without any issues.

Please help me resolve this issue. Here is how the system is configured.

2 Personal Computers connecting to a Switch (or Hub)
Switch connected to Modem, which is connected to Internet Service Provider through a Telephone Line (ADSL)

Comment: This sounds like a problem your ISP could answered.  We don't have the information required to answer it and you don't have the capabilities to provide it to us.

Comment: Actually, I was not sure whether I should take this issue to the ISP. There is no point in consulting ISP, if the problem is on my side. I was hoping someone would ask me to "check this", "check that" kind of advice, so that I could be a little more inclined to believe that the problem is not on my side if all checks are OK.

Comment: You have to eliminate your connection as the problem, we can't help determine if its your connection, because we don't have access to the diagnostic capabilities of your modem.  Why are people so afraid to complain about bad internet service to their provider?

Comment: Maybe you are correct. I should better talk this out to the ISP.

Answer (score 0):

`> I have been using this for many years without any issues.`

That might be the actual culprit, electronics 'gets old' similar to how mechanics wear out (even for light usage) over time. Add higher than normal[1] temperature and the aging speed increases.

Cables and connectors that has been sitting in the same spot "for ages" will also have a tendency to cause similar problems.

[1] "Normal" for the outside of an apparatus; 25-30 degree C - which implies higher temperatures INSIDE it.